# Scala: Function with dynamic contract as argument

Tags: scala, function, constructor, enums

I have the following enum.

```
object Smth extends Enumeration {
    class Value(name: String, func: (String, Int) => Boolean) extends super.Val(name)

    private def opA(index: Int) : Boolean ={
      index > 0
    }
    private def opB(x: String, index: Int) : Boolean ={
      index > 0 && x.length > 0
    }

    val x = new Value("X", opA) // type mismatch error for opA
    val y = new Value("Y", opB)
}
```

Enum constructor takes as an argument a function, of type `(String, Int) => Boolean`. Is it possible to create enum constructor in such a way that it will accept functions with 2 distinct contracts, for example:

```
(String, Int) => Boolean
(Int) => Boolean
```

I am trying to avoid using default value for argument, in function definition.

This is how I would like to use it.

```
if(Smth.x.func(0)) { do smth }
else if(Smth.y.func("str", 0)) { do smthElse }
```

Comment: Just add another constructor.

Comment: If I add an apply method `class Value(val name: String, val func: (String, Int) => Boolean) extends super.Val(name) {
      def apply(name: String, func: (Int) => Boolean): Value = new Value(name, func)
    }` I get an error `found   : Int => Boolean
 required: (String, Int) => Boolean`

Comment: I'll post my suggestion as answer.

Comment: In this case you do not need enum. It will be enough to only have two function. Or somewhere you have `def x: Smth` and then use this x as enum?

Comment: I took you advice. I will mark you answer as correct, to give you credit :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want default value you can do this:

```
class Value(val name: String, val func: (String, Int) => Boolean) extends super.Val(name) { 
    def apply(name: String, func: (Int) => Boolean): Value = 
        new Value(name, (x -> func("default value", x))) 
}
```

Comment: I am trying to avoid default value and was wondering is there any other way of doing it. I'll update the question adding more context.

Comment: Maybe you need two separate class?

Comment: That's the catch I would prefer to group it into a single "entity".

Comment: I've updated the question, with usage I would like to achieve.